# Rotating progressbar download

Tags: wpf, templates

Can any of you tell me of a place that I can download a fancy rotating progressbar?  Or else to use WPF to develop one?  Problem with that though is I don't have any WPF templates.  I am looking for a quick solution also, with little development required.

Comment: What do you mean, you "don't have any WPF templates" ? You can create your own templates, or modify the default ones (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970773.aspx)

Comment: And what exactly is a "rotating progressbar" ? Could you give more details?

Comment: Thanks Thomas!  I went to that link, but it is a case of information overload.  A rotating or fancy progressbar would be a pretty sophisticated/fancy progressbar with a big WOW factor!  Can u recommend where to start with the URL u sent me?

Answer (score 0):

Basic introduction to templating, has a few examples for ProgressBars as well: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163497.aspx)

If you want an indeterminate rotating thing that is fairly easy (e.g. [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35288/WPF-Circular-Progress-Bar.aspx?msg=3105897)), but for it to fill up that might be quite difficult.